# A vehicle moves from rest to a certain distance. Would the distance time graph always be curved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

A vehicle moves from rest to a certain distance. Would the distance time graph always be curved ? Why cannot it be a straight line ?

For example, a car moving from rest to 100m, with a constant velocity of 10m/s . So, if i draw a distance time graph, the line will start from s=0 and end at s=100  ( with t=0 to t=10 ). Would this graph always be curved ? Why can't it be a straight line ?

Comment: You say *For example, a car moving from rest to 100m, with a constant velocity of 10m/s*, but the car cannot both start at rest (i.e. velocity = 0) and have a constant velocity of 10m/s. If the velocity was initially 0 then changed to 10 it wasn't constant.

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): It would be good if OP (or [somebody else](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/16406)?) could provide a clear/crisp/concise title that portrays the heart of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heuristically I'd say yes, it always must be curved if you're starting from rest.

Think of it this way; suppose the graph isn't curved, that is, it's a straight line, then either the straight line is horizontal, or not horizontal.

If the graph (straight line) is horizontal, then the distance isn't changing and you remain at rest.

If the graph is a straight line and not horizontal then you would be moving at a constant velocity, but you started from rest, which is a contradiction.

I'll admit this argument doesn't really account for pathological examples. Maybe one could construct some graph, which in some sort of piece-wise consideration, is made up of straight lines. But I feel like so long as the graph is smooth, then the above argument holds up.

Again, at least with the above logic (I'll admit, quite hand-wavey), it seems like there should be some curvature.

Regarding your example, specifically, if the car has *constant* velocity then the distance/time graph must be a straight line.

Comment: Also regarding you're example, I just re-read it; you either start from rest, or have constant velocity $(10m/s)$, you can't have both. Unless you mean starts from $s = 0m$ (not from rest) and travels to $s = 100m$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the car would have to experience some acceleration from rest to that constant velocity. This part of the graph will have the shape of a parabola if the acceleration is constant as the velocity is constantly changing. The graph would only be a straight line if this acceleration happened during time instant t=0, which is far from what happens in reality.

The graph is however a straight line after this acceleration.

Answer (score 3):

You can see it by making tangent to the curve. Tangent is nothing but the instantaneous velocity in the distance time graph.

[image]

The tangent at $t=0$ must be zero because the velocity is zero at $t=0$ since the car started from rest. You can easily see from the two graphs that the second graph shows it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where the distance-time graph is curved:

[image]

Speed is distance per time. That is, if we pick some time, and draw a line tangential to the distance curve at that point, speed is the slope of the distance curve. If distance is increasing very rapidly, speed is high. If distance is remaining constant, speed is zero.

We then do the same thing again to arrive at acceleration, because acceleration is speed per time. For the example here, the vehicle is stationary for a moment, then someone hits the gas and acceleration increases to some finite value. The vehicle goes faster and faster. Nothing unusual here.

Now, consider the case where the distance vs. time graph is a straight line:

[image]

The vehicle is initially at rest. Then, instantly starts moving at a constant speed. At the moment that it starts moving, what is acceleration?

As speed increases more quickly, acceleration becomes greater. Well, how quickly did speed increase? As fast as possible: instantly. So, acceleration is, at this instant, infinite.

This is problematic, because force is mass times acceleration:

$$ F = ma $$

Assuming an object with some mass, to create a larger acceleration we must apply a greater force. To apply a greater force, we must supply more energy. But, we are looking to supply *infinite* acceleration, which requires *infinite* energy. Not possible.

So: yes, the distance-time graph will always be a curve. Note however, that we can make it *arbitrarily close* to a straight line by increasing the acceleration at the point where the vehicle starts moving, but if you look closely enough it will always take some (arbitrarily small) time to increase speed. There is no physical limit to how high that acceleration can be, but it can't be infinite. And of course, you may break the necks of the occupants, or destroy the vehicle.